# How to modify owl carousel navigation button in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, owl-carousel

I have implemented the owl carousel in my vue project. For example I did this,

```
<carousel 
    :autoplay="true" loop="true" items="1" dots="true" :nav="true" 
     autoplayTimeout="2000" >
     <item .... 1 > 
     <item .... 2 >
     <item .... 3 >
 </carousel>
```

I have used :nav="true" to show the navigation buttons. But it shows **prev** and **next** button at the bottom.

How can I modify the buttons which shows like left and right arrow on the sides.